# Groupby cumulative sum in pandas based on specific condition

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below.

```
B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num   Patient_count
    1     0.4       S1        1          1
    2     0.3       S1        2          1
    3     0.8       S1        3          1
    4     0.3       S1        3          2
    5     0.6       S1        4          1
    6     0.8       S1        5          1
    7     0.9       S1        5          2
    8     0.4       S1        5          3
    9     0.6       S1        5          4
    12    0.9       S2        1          1
    13    0.5       S2        1          2
    14    0.3       S2        2          1
    15    0.7       S2        3          1
    20    0.7       S2        4          1
    16    0.6       S2        5          1
    17    0.8       S2        5          2
    19    0.3       S2        5          3
```

From the above I would like to find the cumulative No_show by Session

```
df['Cum_No_show'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['No_Show'].cumsum()
```

No we get

```
B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num   Patient_count  Cumulative_No_show
    1     0.4       S1        1          1          0.4
    2     0.3       S1        2          1          0.7
    3     0.8       S1        3          1          1.5
    4     0.3       S1        3          2          1.8
    5     0.6       S1        4          1          2.4
    6     0.8       S1        5          1          3.2
    7     0.9       S1        5          2          4.1
    8     0.4       S1        5          3          4.5
    9     0.6       S1        5          4          5.1
    12    0.9       S2        1          1          0.9
    13    0.5       S2        1          2          1.4
    14    0.3       S2        2          1          1.7
    15    0.7       S2        3          1          2.4
    20    0.7       S2        4          1          3.1
    16    0.6       S2        5          1          3.7
    17    0.8       S2        5          2          4.5
    19    0.3       S2        5          3          4.8
```

From the above I would like create a new column named as below

```
U_slot_num = Updated slot number

U_No_show = Updated cumulative no show
```

Whenever cumulative no show > 0.6 change the next slot_num as same as current one and update U_No_show as subtracting 1 as shown in expected output.

Expected output:

```
No_Show  Session slot_num Patient_count Cum_No_show U_slot_num  U_No_show
 0.4       S1        1          1          0.4         1         0.4
 0.3       S1        2          1          0.7         2         0.7
 0.8       S1        3          1          1.5         2         0.5
 0.3       S1        3          2          1.8         3         0.8      
 0.6       S1        4          1          2.4         3         0.4
 0.8       S1        5          1          3.2         4         1.2
 0.9       S1        5          2          4.1         4         0.2
 0.4       S1        5          3          4.5         5         0.6
 0.6       S1        5          4          5.1         6         1.2
 0.9       S2        1          1          0.9         1         0.9
 0.5       S2        1          2          1.4         1         0.4
 0.3       S2        2          1          1.7         2         0.7
 0.7       S2        3          1          2.4         2         0.4
 0.7       S2        4          1          3.1         3         1.1
 0.6       S2        5          1          3.7         3         0.7
 0.8       S2        5          2          4.5         3         0.5
 0.3       S2        5          3          4.8         4         0.8
```

Comment: Use `df['Cumulative_No_show'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['No_Show'].cumsum()`, unfortunately this is dupe :(

Comment: @jezrael edited the question pls hel me to resolve it... it is very difficult for me to solve... Not at all possible for me

Comment: @jezrael should I create new question?

Comment: I think not necessary, I reopen this

Comment: @jezrael pls help me if possible.. If any explanation or clarity required pls feel free to ask

Comment: Just working on it, here are necessary loops.

Comment: One thing, is possible use numba in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212162/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).

Comment: @jezrael any hope in that question. Nobody answered

Comment: I was offline all day, maybe I find some time for check again.

Comment: @Ben.T create a new column called U_slot_num independent of all other columns. where ever we subtract 1 then dont increase other wise increase by 1

Comment: @Ben.T ooh, it is my bad. that is not required. edited the question

Comment: @Ben.T U_slot_num is only depends on U_No_show.  
Start U_slot_num = 1, then
If U_No_show increases then increment U_slot_num by 1. if U_No_show decreases then no increment on U_slot_num..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So similar to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61364013/9274732) later on, i think you need to create a function to return your two columns then `groupby.apply`. And if I understand correctly how you want to increment U_slot_num, then you can do:

```
def create_u_columns (ser):
    arr_ns = ser.to_numpy()
    arr_sn = np.ones(len(ser))
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)-1):
        if arr_ns[i]>0.6:
            # remove 1 to u_no_show
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= 1
        else:
            # increment u_slot_num
            arr_sn[i+1:] += 1
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'U_slot_num':arr_sn, 'U_No_show': arr_ns}, index=ser.index)

df[['U_slot_num', 'U_No_show']] = df.groupby(['Session'])['Cumulative_No_show'].apply(create_u_columns)
```

and you get:

```
print (df)
    B_ID  No_Show Session  slot_num  Patient_count  Cumulative_No_show  \
0      1      0.4      S1         1              1                 0.4   
1      2      0.3      S1         2              1                 0.7   
2      3      0.8      S1         3              1                 1.5   
3      4      0.3      S1         3              2                 1.8   
4      5      0.6      S1         4              1                 2.4   
5      6      0.8      S1         5              1                 3.2   
6      7      0.9      S1         5              2                 4.1   
7      8      0.4      S1         5              3                 4.5   
8      9      0.6      S1         5              4                 5.1   
9     12      0.9      S2         1              1                 0.9   
10    13      0.5      S2         1              2                 1.4   
11    14      0.3      S2         2              1                 1.7   
12    15      0.7      S2         3              1                 2.4   
13    20      0.7      S2         4              1                 3.1   
14    16      0.6      S2         5              1                 3.7   
15    17      0.8      S2         5              2                 4.5   
16    19      0.3      S2         5              3                 4.8   

    U_slot_num  U_No_show  
0          1.0        0.4  
1          2.0        0.7  
2          2.0        0.5  
3          3.0        0.8  
4          3.0        0.4  
5          4.0        1.2  
6          4.0        1.1  
7          4.0        0.5  
8          5.0        1.1  
9          1.0        0.9  
10         1.0        0.4  
11         2.0        0.7  
12         2.0        0.4  
13         3.0        1.1  
14         3.0        0.7  
15         3.0        0.5  
16         4.0        0.8
```

Comment: added similar question.. Please look into this, if you have time..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441460/create-new-rows-based-the-values-of-one-of-the-column-in-pandas